# Connect/Disconnect broadband connection from Telnet in a Thomson TG585?

Tags: router, telnet

I have a Thomson TG585 V7 router (Flash image : 8.2.7.7.0 , Build name  : ZZ5XKB8.277)

I want to Connect and Disconnect the internet via Telnet.

This is very easy from the web interface, but things are getting difficult via telnet. Any ideas?

PS. Even on other routers, where do you go to do this? I am clueless

```
[firewall]     [service]      [connection]   [cwmp]         [dhcp]
[dns]          [dsd]          [dyndns]       [eth]          [atm]
[config]       [debug]        [env]          [expr]         [hostmgr]
[ids]          [igmp]         [interface]    [ip]           [ipqos]
[label]        [language]     [mbus]         [memm]         [mlp]
[nat]          [ppp]          [pptp]         [script]       [sntp]
[software]     [statecheck]   [system]       [systemlog]    [tls]
[upgrade]      [upnp]         [user]         [wireless]     [xdsl]
```

this is the menu of the router via telnet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i feel proud about my self!

Disconnect internet

```
:ppp ifdetach intf=Internet
```

Connect internet

```
:ppp ifattach intf=Internet
```

Comment: I am totally begging you here... how did you learn how to do this? I have a Thompson router as well and I get the same menu system, but I have to troll through the menu's and sub-menu's to do a reboot, which means I can't automate it using software. However, with your command, I can (using a telnet control), and I can make a freeware application so that anyone can restart or reconnect their router at the click of one button (instead of walking upstairs to the router several times a day). I can give you a copy too, and it'll be free. Please please, give me all the leads you have :).

Comment: I was just playing around and figure it out. Also, to make such software you'll need to somehow store (securely) the password of the admin user. The software would have to talk via telnet. To do this, I used c# and a sample telnet I found. It's not that difficult, I've done it for my self. If you have programming questions try asking in stackoverflow.com instead of here.